# Difference in embedded resources naming in VB.NET and C# projects

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, embedded-resource

I have a test project in c #, which I read the embedded resources and returns separated by folders just as I have in the project.

[Project C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZV1z.png)

And I have another one in vb, which I do the same as the previous one but does not read separated by folders.
I don't understand why in one yes, the other not,

[Project VB.NET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXh81.png)

Help me, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you probide the proj files here? It is difficult to find a solution based on your info.

Comment: Hi, looking everywhere I found this, I think it answers my question ... https://weblogs.asp.net/istofix/embedded-resources-in-vb-net-and-c-projects

Comment: hi @Erik, if you think the answer below summarizes your solution, can you accept as answer by clicking the green tick box, so it will serve as reference to others who might have same issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Short:

Embedded resources follows this standard

#### For C'#'

***(RootNameSpace).(PathToResource)***

*RootNameSpace*   `DatabaseMigrationsTest.DbUp`

*Path*                        `"Clients > 001_CreatePersonTable.sql"`

#### For VB.NET

***(RootNameSpace).(ResourceItem)***

*RootNameSpace*   `DatabaseMigrationsTest.DbUp`

*ResourceItem*          `"001_CreatePersonTable.sql"`